# How to get Full Record with MAX as aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with schema (id, date, value, source, ticker). I wanted to get record having highest ID group by date in **sql server**

Example Data

```
ID|date|value|source|ticker

3|10-Dec-2017|10|a|b

1|10-Dec-2017|11|p|q
```

Below query works in Sqlite. Do we know if I can do same with SqlServer

```
select max(id), date, value, source, ticker from table group by date
```

Expected return:-

```
ID|date|value|source|ticker

3|10-Dec-2017|10|a|b
```

Also how I can do same operation on **UNION** of 2 tables with same schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where id = (select max(t1.id) from table t1 where t1.date = t.date);
```

However, you can also use `row_number()` function :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by [date] order by id desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like below :

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
join (
      select max(id) as id, [date] from table1
      group by [date]
     ) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0cd15/3)